# Common files for projects in solution C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, common-files

I have two projects in a single solution in Visual Studio 2015 and I want to add common files to it (both header and source files that will be used by both projects).
I looked for Add as link, but it doesn't seem to be available to C++.

How do I do it?

Comment: Just add the files, they don't need to be in the project directory.